# Vuex change state in diferent routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vuex, ecma

I'm trying to change the state of my Vuex Store with the mutations, and I also have routes in my application. In my default component (the first route) has a button that changes my user.name state, and I have a second component (the second route) that show to me the user.name. In my first component, when I call the mutation to change the user.name state it shows to me the new user.name, but this doesn't become different of the first state.

For example: In my first user.name state I have "John Dave" and when I click on the button that calls the mutation CHANGE_USER(), this has to change to "David Lionel", but don't work.

**Store**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: {
            name: 'John Dave',
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        changeUser (state, payload) {
            state.user = payload;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getName(state) {
            return state.user;
        }
    }
});
```

**First component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{user}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            user() {
                const { name } = this.$store.getters.getName;
                return name;
            },

        },
    };
</script>
```

**Second component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{user}}
    <button @click="changeUser() ">
      Change user
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      user() {
        const { name } = this.$store.state.user;
        return `My user is ${name}`
      },
    },

    methods: {
      changeUser() {
        const payload = {
            name: 'Name changed',
            email: 'vitor@v.cm',
            level: 'ADM',
        };

        this.$store.commit('changeUser', payload);
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code, please?

Comment: Edited, @ceejayoz

Comment: I suspect the `const` in `const { name } = this.$store.getters.getName;` is likely giving you trouble. Try just `return this.$store.getters.getName` in your two components' `computed` functions?

Comment: Do you have errors in your console? Because if I try this out it seems to work for the most part: https://codesandbox.io/s/kmp033244v

Comment: One of the things that may be happening is that your first component does not "see" that the payload has been changed, because you override the reference. You can avoid that by using `Vue.set(base, property, payload)`, or `Vue.set(state, 'user', payload)` in your case.

Comment: I tried to use Vue.set, but this isn't working. I receive a log saying that state isn't defined.

Comment: Do this: open the [first](https://23p7jlpqor.codesandbox.io/#/ "first component") and also the [second](https://23p7jlpqor.codesandbox.io/#/second "second component"). Click on "Change user" on the second component. This may have changed the state on the first one, right? But it does not do it.